# In sql divide row1 by row,row2 by row3.... . .and store the output third column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table, Now I need to perform division on amt column and update the data int CalcAmt

```
month  amt   CalcAmt
JAN   10000  NULL
FEB   20000  NULL
MAR   30000  NULL
APR   40000  NULL
```

eg: (FEB/JAN) then store output in CalcAmt of Feb,
    (MAR/FEB) then store output in CalcAmt of MAR,

Expected Output:

```
month  amt   CalcAmt
JAN   10000  0
FEB   20000  2
MAR   30000  1.5
APR   40000  1.33
```

Comment: You could join the table on itself by id+1 (if you have auto increment values). And than add in the select of this statement sth to divide row t.amt / t2.amt

Comment: But that would be just the select...

Comment: `I tried this and its working :
set @sr = (select top 1 Sr_No from #tempo order by #tempo.Sr_No desc);
WHILE (@sr > 0)
BEGIN
 if @sr > 1
 begin
 set @Value = (select [Sales(INR)] from #tempo where Sr_No = @sr)
 set @value2 = (select [Sales(INR)] from #tempo where Sr_No = (@sr-1))
 set @value3 = (select @Value/@value2)

 Update #tempo set Gropm =  @Value3 where #tempo.Sr_No = @sr
 
 set @sr = @sr - 1;
 end
 else
 begin
 Update #tempo set Gropm =  0 where #tempo.Sr_No = 1
 set @sr = @sr - 1;
 end`

Comment: Nice, glad  it worked ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done through `LEAD/LAG`, Since you are using `Sql Server 2008`you cannot use `LEAD/LAG` function. Instead use can generate row number for each row and self join the same table with row number + 1 to fetch the previous row data.

**Note:** You need add the remaining `months` in the order in `case` statement if you have any.

As a side note you should not use *[reserved keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)* as object name **ex:** `MONTH`

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Rn=CASE [month] 
                     WHEN 'Jan' THEN 1 
                     WHEN 'feb' THEN 2 
                     WHEN 'mar' THEN 3 
                     ELSE 4 
                   END, 
                * 
         FROM   YOURTABLE) 
SELECT A.month, 
       A.amt, 
       CalcAmt = A.amt / NULLIF(b.amt ,0)
FROM   cte A 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN cte B 
                    ON A.rn = b.rn + 1
```

- [**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02b83/6)

If you want to update the table then use this.

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Rn=CASE [month] 
                     WHEN 'Jan' THEN 1 
                     WHEN 'feb' THEN 2 
                     WHEN 'mar' THEN 3 
                     ELSE 4 
                   END, 
                * 
         FROM   YOURTABLE) 
UPDATE C 
SET    C.calcamt = D.calcamt 
FROM   cte C 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT A.month, 
                          A.amt, 
                          calcamt=A.amt / b.amt 
                   FROM   cte A 
                          LEFT OUTER JOIN cte B 
                                       ON A.rn = b.rn + 1) D 
               ON C.[month] = D.[month]
```